# How to use Mathematica in AWS cloud?

Tags: notebooks, education, webmathematica, mathematica-online, general-utilities

I have a free account in AWS cloud for 1 year for $750$ hours. How to run Mathematica in AWS cloud? And is Mathematica chargeable in AWS cloud?

Comment: I presume you're talking about an AWS EC2 virtual server? I have don't have any experience with running Mathematica in EC2, but it would probably help if you could post the specs of the server you have in mind and perhaps someone could tell you if it will work well. Not all of their server configurations are meant to run software like Mathematica, and you probably don't have 750 hours of free time on just any server configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I am talking about AWS EC2 virtual server.

Answer (score 9):

Install version 11.3 of the [player](https://www.wolfram.com/player/), write your `script.wl`
and run `wolframscript -f script.wl`

If you want a GUI check https://github.com/mmatera/iwolfram and run jupyter remotely. On AWS VM run `jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=7000` then on you local machine  `ssh -NfL localhost:7000:localhost:6001 <IP>`)

Comment: Instead of CDF now you also have the option to install Wolfram Engine and get a free developer license